# Adjust BitmapFields Width in HorizontalFieldManager according device width

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, horizontalfieldmanager

I am new in BB development,

Please suggest me how i can adjust BitmapFields Width which are in HorizontalFieldManager
to adjust it in Device width.

I am overriding Sublayout method to get this

Now it look like this....I am getting expected o/p for Simulator 9550

[image: Bottom Bar]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a customBitmapField class which extends BitmapField. Override getPreferredWidth() method and return (Display.getWidth()/3) so the bitmapfield takes up a third of the device display. you will have to handle how it looks in smaller devices as well as the text might not fit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `PillButtonSet` component, you can find it in the advanced UI package.
see here: [Advanced UI](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/documentation/ww_java_uinavigation/Advanced_UI_components_and_managers_1970227_11.html)